# Proving the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is orthogonal. (Proof check)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I've got the following I'm trying to prove and want to make sure my proof is sound.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, prove $A^{-1}$ orthogonal.

Proof

a square matrix is said to be orthogonal if its transpose is the same as its inverse, that is if
$$
A^{-1}=A^{T}
$$
thus,
$$
(A^{-1})^{-1}=A=(A^{T})^{T}=(A^{-1})^{T}
$$
So by definition, $A^{-1}$ is orthogonal. []

Any suggestions on how to make this better would be great.

Comment: No, this is good!

Comment: Alright, thanks @TheoBendit